# Google Chrome hanging on pageload

Tags: google-chrome

I have chrome 37 and problem just started today.

When I open Chrome I cannot view any pages. It just hangs and get eventually Page Unresponsive Window with option to kill page or to wait.

Even pages like `chrome://settings` have the same problem!

I also tried disabling extensions but that doesn't help!

Internet is working fine with other Browsers.

I downloaded standalone installer from Google, reinstalled (System wide version), chrome starts automatically and everything working again. But when I close chrome and restart - problem starts again! Reinstall - it works, close and restart - problem comes back.

**Edit:**
After rebooting computer, as expected, things started working again. But this still doesn't explain what was causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to clarify your OS.

Assuming Windows, if you ever reproduce the issue, Use `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` to open up the Task Manager, go to the Processes tab, and check out the state of any chrome.exe processes. The CPU and Memory loads on the threads can give you insight into what might be going on. (It sounds like a memory leak to me.)

Answer (score 0):

As a note for future visitors, I found that Windows update KB3150513 was causing some sort of conflict with Chrome [as detailed here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/c1eUzQ4gwps;context-place=forum/chrome) . Uninstalling this windows update remove the issue.